# Python egg with package_dir .. seems to break require

Tags: python, setuptools

I just noticed a strange fact with setuptools (actually, I needed 3 hours to find the reason):

- Build an egg with the following setup() call

```python
setup(  
  name='SimpleEgg',  
  version='1.0',  
  packages=['SimpleEgg'],  
  long_description="",  
  package_dir = {'': '..'},  
  classifiers=[],  
  install_requires=[]  
)
```

- Copy the egg in site-packages/
- Execute the following commands

```python
from pkg_resources import require   
require("SimpleEgg")
```

that throws pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: SimpleEgg

When I change my directory layout so that I can remove the package_dir line, everything works as expected.

Is it possible to get a working egg even with the package dir paramter?

Beste Regards, Peter

Comment: Egg packages are tricky, at least, it happened to me. Then when I solved all my issues, I created a tool called https://pypi.python.org/pypi/machete/, which generates working code target to become an egg package. Perhaps you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you don't need the `package_dir` directive.

Read this [setuptools tutorial](http://bashelton.com/2009/04/setuptools-tutorial/#setup.py-package_dir) for further information:

> This directive is only needed if you provide a specific directory as an argument to
>   find_packages. You can safely ignore this directive if you omit the first argument to 
>   find_packages.